# Where could I see the question that I have marked as favorites?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

On Android App I am not able to go to question that I have marked as favorites. Did you forget add this section on Android App or it is so hidden?

Comment: They didn't forget, it's simply more complicated than it sounds like, involving backend (API) changes.